# defining a javascript var using php echo

Tags: javascript, php

I've seen several responses to this question already - so I'm sure someone will be very quick to mark this as a duplicate, but I haven't seen the answer to this particular question in any other threads.

I have two test files:  **a.php and a.js**

in a.php, I define

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

which works fine.

I then make a call to a separate a.js file, wherein I have:

```
var partNumber = " <?php echo $q; ?>" ;
```

This does not work, as partNumber is literally **`<?php echo $q;?>`**

In several of the posts I've read on this topic, I've seen BOTH of the following as the top rated, accepted answer:

```
var partNumber = " <?php echo $q; ?>" ; //with quotes
```

and

```
var partNumber =  <?php echo $q; ?> ;  //without quotes
```

However, neither of these work for me.  Without quotes causes my code not to execute, (I assume because javascript needs to be error free to execute successfully, and this causes an error,) while the one with quotes just outputs what I literally typed in.

what is the difference between these two, and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Unless your server is configured to parse .js files as PHP, you won't be able to have PHP in a .js file.

Comment: The quotes doesn't matter, the issue you're having is that javascript files are not interpreted by PHP, only .php files are.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I don't get it, couldn't you just use echo 'var partNumber = $_GET["q"];' and pass all of your JS cars that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If html from a.php includes a.js:

a.php

```
<html><head>
<script type="application/json" id="myvars"><?=json_encode(["partNumber"=>$_GET["q"]]);?></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/a.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

a.js

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    var myvars = $.parseJSON($("#myvars").html()), 
        partNumber = myvars.partNumber;
    alert(partNumber);
});
```

if not you should look into AJAX.

Edit: maybe a bit too complex for an example... but it is compatible with [Content Security Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy), if you validate the GET q parameter.

Comment: so at least that gets the two to talk to one another - thank you.  In my console, for `var partNumber = $.parseJSON($("#myvars").html());` and `console.log("part number is " + partNumber);` I'm getting `part number is [object Object] `

Comment: @JohnWu Ah yes, it's a JSON object. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

In order to use

```
var partNumber = " <?php echo $q; ?>";
```

in your JS files the server must be configured to handler files with `js` extension as executable PHP files. Unlikely this is your case. So you can't make PHP variable resolve in the javascript file.

However accepted answers you mentioned, embed `<script>` tags into HTML files, which are typically processed by PHP interpreter (if they have `.php` extension).

Comment: EXACTLY.  that was the key difference - all of the JS I saw was always within a <script> tag in the actual file itself.

Answer (score 2):

Proper way:

```
var foo = <?php echo json_encode($var); ?>;
```

Anything else is "bad". If you don't output CORRECT javascript code, you introduce a syntax error and your entire `<script>` block gets killed. Always use json_encode(), and you'll be outputting syntactically correct JS data.

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1

The reason your variable is not being written is simply because your javascript is in a separate file as you said:

> I then make a call to a separate a.js file

You cannot read a PHP variable in a separate .js file.

The correct way to pass a variable from PHP to javascript, would be to place the javascript inline (in the same document), and then calling it like so:

Short hand (requires `short_open_tags` set in php.ini):

```
var partNumber = "<?= json_encode($q); ?>" ;
```

Or what most people will do:

```
var partNumber = "<?php echo json_encode($q); ?>" ;
```

*The reason you should use `json_encode` is to ensure that no matter what is in `$q`, it will not break the javascript as `json_encode` will always output valid javascript.*

### Question 2

To answer your second question, the difference between the two blocks of code are that one will be written like so:

```
var partNumber = "1";
```

and the other will be written:

```
var partNumber = 1;
```

It depends whether you would like `partNumber` to be read as an integer or a string...